# How to get argument of a variant?

Tags: rust

Having these enums

```
pub enum Symbol {
    X,
    O,
}

pub enum CellContent {
    Move(Symbol),
    Empty,
}
```

and

```
let cell_content = CellContent::Move(Symbol::X);
```

how can I get the `Symbol` ? Of course if it's of variant `Move(Symbol)`

This doesn't work

```
        if cell_0_0 == Move(a_symbol) {  
            return Some(a_symbol);
        }
```

I cannot also do the following because I must do nothing (code must continue evaluation); and the following doesn't even compile at all !

```
        match cell_0_0 {
            Move(symbol) => return symbol;
            _ => // do nothing;
        }

        // code must go on to check further conditions
```

| I still have some problem with basic syntax of rust, so I'm experiencing making some basic programs

### So question is

How to

- check if my variable is a variant of `Move(Symbol)`
- if yes return (a copy of) symbol
- else do nothing, so code can go on and do more checks
  ?

### Edit 1: Full  (not working) code

```
pub fn some_one_win(&self) -> Option<Symbol> {
    let cell_0_0: CellContent = self.table[0][0];
    let cell_0_1: CellContent = self.table[0][1];
    let cell_0_2: CellContent = self.table[0][2];
    if cell_0_0 == cell_0_1 && cell_0_0 == cell_0_2 {
        match cell_0_0 {
            Move(symbol) => return symbol;
            _ => // how to 'do nothing' here ?;
        }
    }
    let cell_1_0: CellContent = self.table[1][0];
    let cell_1_1: CellContent = self.table[1][1];
    let cell_1_2: CellContent = self.table[1][2];
    if cell_1_0 == cell_1_1 && cell_1_0 == cell_1_2 {
        match cell_1_0 {
            Move(symbol) => return symbol;
            _ => // how to 'do nothing' here ?;
        }
    }
    ... and so on ..
}
```

Comment: You might get it to compile by replacing "do nothing" with the empty tuple `()`. In any case please post the full code.

Comment: You're probably looking for something like `if let CellContent::Move(symbol) = cell { return symbol; }`. See https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-03-if-let.html

Comment: @Pitaj it works !!! For precision I am returning `Some(symbol)` ! i didn't suspect I can get symbol out of a let directly! Wow ... I love rust

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I cannot also do the following because I must do nothing (code must continue evaluation); and the following doesn't even compile at all !
>
> ```
> match cell_0_0 {
>     Move(symbol) => return symbol;
>     _ => // do nothing;
> }
> ```

You can do that, if you get the syntax right:

```
match cell_0_0 {
    CellContent::Move(symbol) => {
        return Some(symbol);
    }
    _ => {}  // do nothing
}
```

But as PitaJ mentioned, when there’s only one pattern plus `_`, the `if let` construct is usually a cleaner alternative:

```
if let CellContent::Move(symbol) = cell_0_0 {
    return Some(symbol);
}
```

Comment: I am in love with rust. And thanks for your clear, concise but complete answer !

Comment: Side question: is there a way to use `cell_0_0` instead of `Some(a_symbol)` to get the symbol? something like `cell_0_0.some_value_contained()`  ? Just to learn alternative syntax if available

Comment: You can add a associated function in an `impl CellContent` block that would allow such usage.

Comment: @realtebo: There [isn’t a built-in one yet](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/issues/2960), but yes, you can implement that.